# Move out put from one console log to another logger that print to file

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

I have a logger that prints to the console early during application startup. It is set up like so.

```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateBootstrapLogger();
    Log.Information("Starting");
```

Eventually, as we begin to spin up services and read configuration we will spin up our main logger for the application as we now have progressed far enough in the startup to do so. We are using serilog and liek so :

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();

    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

Here is my issue, if the application fails to startup before we set up the second logger (one that will print to my logfile) I loose all context of what happened as the initial logger is just printing to console.

Is there a way to say in my try catch to dump all past "log output" into the same file I use in the second?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for your coding language